# Drawing a tree using pstricks without using many \pslsystem commands

Tags: pstricks, pst-lsystem

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-lsystem,pstricks,pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
\psset{unit=1cm}
\def\Myfig{\pslsystem[Start=F,F={FF-[-F+F+F]+[+F-F-F]},Angle=22.5,BaseLength=2pt,usecolor=4](0,-2)}
\def\MyFig{\pslsystem[Start=F,F={F[F+F+F][F-F-F]F},Angle=22.5,BaseLength=2.5pt,usecolor=3](0,-2)}
\rput(6,5){\Myfig}
\rput(5.4,5){\MyFig}
\rput(5,5){\psscalebox{-1 1}{\Myfig}}
\psframe[fillcolor=green,fillstyle=solid,framearc=0.5,linecolor=lightgray](5.8,5)(5.2,-5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

I want to draw as figure BUT NOT USING MUCH `\pslsystem`!

P/s: Sure the result generated will not like as figure! ...

Comment: I think I would produce such a complicated picture with something like MS Paint, export it as an image file, and include it in the document, instead of drawing the picture using PSTricks or TikZ.

Comment: @JouleV Drawing L-system with PSTricks or TikZ is so beautiful. You can read manual about L-system :-)

Comment: Here's a [link to the `pst-lsystem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-lsystem/doc/pst-lsystem-doc.pdf).

Comment: The documentation is on any TeX system, no need to download it from a website.

Comment: @Herbert: It's smidge faster if you don't always have a terminal open, don't know about `texdoc` or didn't know this was the manual being referred to.